# How do I make a Chicago style title page?

Tags: titles

Like this: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/media/pdf/1300991022_717.pdf. It needs some text a third of the way down the page, and some two thirds of the way down. I am using the article document class.

Comment: I like to lay out title pages using tikzpagenodes.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286802/usage-of-vspace-command-from-top-of-the-page/286820?s=3|0.7020#286820 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0936#273885

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some rubber length available, like `\vfill` or `\vspace{\stretch{number}}`

With `\vfill`, tex will spread the remaining space on the page evenly for every `\vfill` there is.  So one before the first part, on in between and one after will give you what you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vfill
Fisrt text one third of the way
\vfill
Second part two third of the way
\vfill
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

For additional control, you could use `\vspace{\stretch{number}}` Tex will add the numbers and spread the remaining space accordingly.  In the following example, the space will be one part before, two par in between and three part after

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
Fisrt text one third of the way
\vspace{\stretch{2}}
Second part two third of the way
\vspace{\stretch{3}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```